# Como passar parâmetro para modal, consultar Mysql e dar retorno em html

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando passar uma variável para uma modal, realizar uma consulta de dar um retorno em `html`, pois os dados virão formatados em uma tabela. Tentei algumas sugestões como alternativas, mas estou tendo dificuldade para fazer a coisa funcionar, tenho esse linha que invoca a modal:

```
<a href="#ModalDetalhes" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $Eventos->IdEvento; ?>" data-target="#edit-modal"><?php echo $Eventos->Data; ?></a>
```

O script que fará o envio da variável está assim:

```
$('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  var $modal = $(this),

    IdEvento = e.relatedTarget.id;

    console.log("EVENTO: " + IdEvento);

  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pDetalhesEventos.php',
    data: 'IdEvento=' + IdEvento,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html();
    }
  });
})
```

O php está assim configurado:

```
require_once "../_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php";
require_once "../_classes/crud.class.php";

// Atribui uma conexão PDO   
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
// Atribui uma instância da classe Crud, passando como parâmetro a conexão PDO e o nome da tabela  
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'cadEventos');

// DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
$IdEvento = (isset($_GET['IdEvento'])) ? $_GET['IdEvento'] : '';

// INICIALIZANDO O ARRAY
$arrayParam = array(); 

// BUSCA COM FILTRO 
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(Data, '%d/%m/%Y') as Data FROM cadEventos WHERE IdEvento = ?";             
$arrayParam  = array($IdEvento);
$Resultado  = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParam, TRUE); 
$retorno = count($Resultado);
```

O que tentei foi fazer isso, passando a variável pela `url` recuperando por `get` e `post`:

```
url: "cliente.php?id=123",
```

A modal está assim:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#edit-modal" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $Eventos->IdEvento; ?>" data-target="#edit-modal">#Modal</a>

<div id="edit-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalhes do Evento</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body edit-content">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A variável está correta, pois consigo vê-la no console.

Imagens do console do FF:

[image: Console]

Comment: Pra chamar a modal ou vc usa _href_ ou usa _data-target_. Substitua `href="#ModalDetalhes"` por `href="#edit-modal"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesta linha dentro da função success você está usando o .html() sem passar nenhum argumento para a função .html().

```
$modal.find('.edit-content').html();
```

Comment: Se você quiser realmente receber a variável pelo GET no PHP você pode mudar o trecho da URL.

`url: 'pDetalhesEventos.php',` para `url: 'pDetalhesEventos.php?IdEvento=' + IdEvento',`

Comment: Olá @Matheus Prado, no console do Firefox eu consigo ver o conteúdo no "response" mas não exibe na modal.

Comment: Você diz que o PHP esta retornando da forma correta para a variável 'data' dentro da função success do ajax? E que mesmo assim seu modal não é preenchido?

Comment: Resposta principal foi editada, espero que seja esse o problema :D

Comment: Obrigado @Matheus Prado, uma marcada vergonhosa, mas sua ajuda minimizou isso, value mesmo.

Comment: Disponha ... :D